# IIS applicationHost 'setEnvironment' attribute

Tags: iis, localdb

```
<add name="ASP.NET v4.0" autoStart="true" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" managedPipelineMode="Integrated">
<processModel identityType="ApplicationPoolIdentity" loadUserProfile="true" setProfileEnvironment="true" />
</add>
```

I'm adding that in appliationHost config of IIS to solve localDb problem in IIS what I see in this article

> http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/12/09/using-localdb-with-full-iis-part-1-user-profile.aspx

Can you guys help me to avoid this error?

> Unrecognized attribute 'setProfileEnvironment'

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are attempting to place the value inside of an actual application pool.  That attribute lives outside of a defined application pool, and lives in appicationpooldefaults.

```
<applicationPoolDefaults>
<processModel identityType="ApplicationPoolIdentity" loadUserProfile="true" setProfileEnvironment="true" />
<applicationPoolDefaults>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Quick search](http://forums.iis.net/t/1178788.aspx/1) for the error you provided points to outdated or broken IIS (the assembly that implements `setProfileEnvironment` attribute, or one of its dependencies, is either missing or broken). At least that's best guess based on the data provided.